# Disable specific Block is getting cached in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, custom-block, block-cache

I am trying to disable cache for specific block,

Have used below code.

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">            
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="custom_block" template="custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Index.php**

```
<?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

 class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
   public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
      array $data = []
      ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = false;
     }


public function customHtml()
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        if (curl_exec($ch)) {               
            $contents = curl_exec($ch);
            return $contents;
        }
 }
   public function getCacheLifetime()
    { 
       return null;
    }
 }
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend/templates/custom.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->customHtml(); ?>
```

Used **getCacheLifetime** and **_isScopePrivate** but not working. Please someone guide me on this.

**Note: cacheable="false"  is not recommended**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you disable a single block caching, this will disable the whole page caching. Since you're adding the block in default.xml layout file, I think you should avoid doing this. Instead of disabling the block caching, you'd better use private content. You can find more info here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Comment: @MagestyApps, I gone through the above link which is not so clear and I didn't get the solution, Can you please update me as answer for my issue please...

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a di.xml inside app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="add_custom_name_here" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Index</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Inside `item name="add_any_unique_custom_name"` and assign a block class for which you want to disable cache `Vendor\Module\Block\Index`

Now create a block and return a function in which you want to disable cache

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
    
    use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;
    
    class Index implements SectionSourceInterface
    {
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSectionData()
        {
            $data = ['profile' => 'abc' ]; //get dynamic data here instead of 'abc'
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Create `default.xml` inside `view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="Vendor.PrivateContent"
                   template="Vendor_Moduel::private.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="add_custom_name_here" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/custom_section</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Next step is to create a `custom_section.js` file inside `view/frontend/web/js/custom_section.js`

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.add_custom_name_here = customerData.get('add_custom_name_here');
        }
    });
});
```

Now inside your any phtml file call this script

```
<div data-role="custom-section" data-bind="scope: 'add_custom_name_here'">
    <span class="content-type" data-bind="text: custom_section().profile"></span>
</div>    
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=custom-section]": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout(); ?>
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, still I have some questions, what should i replace in the block function  getSectionData().. At present there are many functions are created in my block file, Need some assistance on that.

Comment: The data for which you want to disable cache and update on every refresh should be return inside $data = ['profile' => 'abc' ]; instead of 'abc' you can get data here dynamically like $data = ['profile' => $update_without_cache ];

Comment: Sorry if I am asking silly, Still not cleared to me, I have many functions defined in the block, what is the content here , get data here dynamically like $data = ['profile' => $update_without_cache ];

Comment: I updated the Block code, can you please help me with the same code.

Comment: I followed the answer you given, but still the page is getting cached, can we check is there any other pages caching and remove it?